# Dynamically build array of values by indirect column reference

Tags: excel, excel-2010, sumifs

[image: Sample Scorecard]

I'm building a yearly scorecard (sample shown above).  The requirements for the scorecard are listed below.

- Year to Date values must cumulatively add each of the previous period values (circled in orange).

  - P1 = P1
  - P2 = P1 + P2
  - P3 = P1 + P2 + P3  (etc)
- Year to Date formulas must all be the exact same, dynamically referencing the required columns and required rows so that they can be easily copied from period to period (on going).

With this formula I was trying looking at row 2 with each of the column indicators in it, and trying to test for ISTEXT() to add up the values in the ROW()-1.  Using concatenate to build a string that references a row range might not be the best way to do it.

Example:  If I have values in row 55
=SUM(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(ROW()-1, ":", ROW()-1)))

=SUM(INDEX(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(ROW()-1, ":", ROW()-1)),MATCH(ISTEXT(2:2),2:2,0)))

I was trying something like a horizontal sumifs() formula with little luck, attempting to use the modulus value of the column() function as a logical test.

formula doesn't work 
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT(ROW()-1&":"&ROW()-1), MOD(COLUMN()-2, 6), 0)

Or Using some other method of testing which columns to add.
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(ROW()-1, ":", ROW()-1)), IF(ISTEXT(2:2), 1, 0), TRUE)

If I change my lettering in Row 2 (N, H, T) to just "X" then test for X that works, but this formula doesn't factor in the requirement for only adding values from current and prior periods.
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(ROW()-1, ":", ROW()-1)),2:2, "X")

I don't know of a way to accomplish adding up a dynamic number of indirect cell references based on the column you're in.  So lets say its row 55 in period 3, I would need a formula that looks in row 2, sees each of the column values (H, N, T) and adds up H55, N55, T55).  That same formula would need to construct a different list based on if its in period 2.  (H, N), (H55, N55).

Maybe I need to rethink my approach entirely?  Write VBA instead?

Edit
To better expand on what the data model is, to address some comments, I've thrown some dummy values and dirty formulas in.

[image]

Have a look at service level vs. service level year to date (YTD).  Service level is just a flat data entry of weekly performance, then the Summary column is a simple average of the weekly performance in order to report period performance.  The YTD number is an average of the period numbers, so these values progressively roll up.

The formulas I'm trying to write are for the summary columns, both period value and YTD values.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your data layout is.  If it's you want to sum all values in row 55, up to and including the column the formula is in, try `=SUMPRODUCT(55:55*--(COLUMN(55:55)<=COLUMN()))`.  If not, please explain more (don't worry about the formula you have tried, just explain the data layout).  If there are other values in row 55 not to be summed, I can provide a mod to this formula

Answer (score 0):

For column T use:

```
=SUM(IF(MOD(COLUMN($H:T),6)=2,$H$1:T$1,0))
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

change the `$H$1:T$1` to the rownumber you need to sum (it will only sum every sixth column starting with `H`)

Having UPEH at Row 9 and this code in row 10 then `=SUM(IF(MOD(COLUMN($H:T),6)=2,$H$9:T$9,0))`

If set correct one time you can copy paste it as you need it (as long as it stays with just sum every 6th column starting at `H`)

for making it more dynamically you may better use:

```
=SUM(IF($A$4:T$4="Summary",$A$9:T$9,0))
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

it checks for Row 4 to contain "Summary" to get the values to sum :)

**EDIT**
However, if you want to have exactly the same formula in each part you would need to use something like that:

```
=SUM(IF(AND($4:$4="Summary",COLUMN($4:$4)<=COLUMN(),OFFSET($1:$1,ROW()-2,),0))
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

it sums all the cells 1 row over itself from the beginning till (including) the own column for all columns containing "Summary" in row 4
however, this may get pretty slot pretty fast (calcs a LOT) ^^

**BIG HINT**: Just looking at what you have/need

lets asume the cells to add are in row 1 and the output in row 2...
we also skip the columns not to calculate (to make it easy)...

```
A2 would be just A1
B2 would be A1 + B1
C2 would be A1 + B1 + C1... but wait!

A1 + B1 = B2 so better -> C2 = B2 + C1
leads to:  
R2Cx = R2C(x-1) + R1Cx
```

if you just use that behavior in column N (that it is the value over it and the calculated value to the left (column H)) and also write it that way, you could just copy it and paste it in column T and you will get `=T(above) + N(calculated)`. check it :)

Comment: @pnuts yeah... but it took me a long time to just notice it could be used as a base for the following week... i'd never put so much effort into creating array-formulas having such an easy and extremely fast way to solve it :/

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what your data layout is.

So, assuming:

1. Labels that identify columns to sum are in row 2
2. Values to sum are in row 55
3. Formula is to sum values in row 55, which have a non-blank entry in row 2, and sum values in columns up to and including the column the formula is in

Formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT($55:$55,--(COLUMN($55:$55)<=COLUMN()),--($2:$2<>""))
```